# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^

Tags: php, regex

when i run this in php 5.3:

```
public function isValidEmail($email)
{
    //$pattern = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$";   
return (preg_match($pattern, $email)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I get this message:

```
 Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' in......
```

any idea what it should be?

Comment: You have no delimiters for your regex `$pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/";`

Comment: Your `$pattern` is also commented out.

Comment: Be sure to use preg_quote to backslash any other slashes in your pattern like the following: $pattern = '/' . preg_quote("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", '/') . '/';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is pointed out already, your regex pattern is not enclosed by **[delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**. As well, you can avoid using the ternary operator, it is not necessary to return the value of `preg_match()`.

```
function isValidEmail($email) {
    $pattern = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i';
    return preg_match($pattern, $email);
}
```

You may consider using the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function to check whether an email address is well-formed or not.

```
function isValidEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 1:0;
}
```

Comment: The function `filter_var` doesn't like ordinary and valid emails like `this.example@gmail.com`. If it has a dot `.` before the `@`, the function returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

your pattern should like this, put '/' after and before the pattern.

```
/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})+$/
```

and + sign before the last $